# Why Scrapy Udemy gives response 403 error?

Tags: python, scrapy

I was trying to use scrapy shell to see response.css result of the page basically. the simple code snippet which i was using is response.css("title::text").extract(). Normally this should give you the title of the webpage. But i understand that it is not possible for Udemy. On the other hand i used it for amazon and it is working fine. Any comments?

```
scrapy shell "https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=python&src=sac&kw=python"
response.css("title::text").extract()
['Access to this page has been denied.']
```

on the other hand this below one is working fine.

```
scrapy shell "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=garlic+press&crid=2DY5U90PELGKN&sprefix=garlic+pres%2Caps%2C286&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_11"

response.css("title::text").extract()
['Amazon.com: garlic press']
```

EDIT:

```
scrapy shell --set=USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0' "https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=python&src=sac&kw=python"
response.css("h4::text").extract()
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Udemy is trying to prevent you from using automation scraping.  It returns an HTTP 403 response, and in that response's body there's some text stating:

> Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website.

They're blocking when the value of the HTTP header `User-Agent` is not something that they want to access their content.  Luckily, headers can be spoofed.

```
scrapy shell --set=USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0' "https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=python&src=sac&kw=python"
```

Ought to work (though, I don't have python/scrapy on this machine, so I didn't test)

edit: I'm not certain about the legalities of circumventing their bot protection... Make sure to check your local laws before you use this advice.

Comment: thanks, user agent worked and now i get response 200, but interestingly now i run code in edit section and it gives empty list.

Comment: I would look at `response` alone to see if the title is where you think it is.  Parsing HTML can be a pain and takes a bit of trial and error.

Comment: response.css("title::text").extract() is working fine now after using Useragent and gives result ['Online Courses - Anytime, Anywhere | Udemy'] with success. But now i am not able to print out name of each course on the page.